# Can't Navigate to Identity Logout Page -ASP.Net Core 3.1-

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-identity

I've been extending and modifying the IdentityUser class and have made the corresponing EntityFramework migrations adjustments the Database reflects the changes and I started up the site. What I found is that everywhere that is said IdentityUser previously had to be changed to the new User class (a child of IdentityUser). I've made the changes which required some adjustments to the Startup.cs file. Now I can login but am unable to logout. It seem that my site has been completely locked out of the generated Razor pages in the "Identity" Area. So, here is my Startup.cs page maybe something is wrong in there.

```
namespace InTheCloud
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _env = env;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
        private OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; set; }
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();

            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
            //services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config => {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                
                config.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
                    new TokenProviderDescriptor(
                        typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>)));
                config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add a DbContext to store your Database Keys
            services.AddDbContext<MyKeysContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyKeysContext")));

            // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyKeysContext>();
           
            services.AddScoped<Services.AppVariables>();

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                //options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status100Continue;
                options.HttpsPort = 5000;

            });

            services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
                //options.ExcludedHosts.Add("example.com");
                //options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.example.com");
            });

            //services.AddCors();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>>();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dataContext)
        {

            dataContext.Database.Migrate();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            //app.UseSession();

            //app.UseCors(x => x
            //    .AllowAnyOrigin()
            //    .AllowAnyMethod()
            //    .AllowAnyHeader());

            

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
        
    }
}
```

Maybe you have some ideas kind weird to have access to the razor pages just stop like that! Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you should map your Area folder as well.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyArea",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```